# SQL sub-query will only check one column, fails when ask to check 2 for the same query

Tags: sql

When I run the following code in SQL Server 2014 Express, it works fine to get all children of this father for a family relation table.

```
select Name 
from Persons 
where ID in (select personID 
             from FAMILY 
             where fatherID in (select fatherID.ID 
                                from Persons fatherID 
                                where fatherID.Name = 'Louis Vingo'))
```

But when I try and check both the mother and father with this code I get an error.

```
select Name 
from Persons 
where ID in (select personID 
             from FAMILY 
             where (fatherID, motherID) in (select fatherID.ID, motherID.ID  
                                            from Persons fatherID, Persons motherID 
                                            where fatherID.Name = 'Louis Vingo' 
                                              and motherID.Name = 'Dianne Vingo'))
```

Error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near ','.
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Any suggestions I have read that it may be due to the code only taking one parameter in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your syntax, you need *two* `in` conditions:

```
where fatherID in (select p.ID from Persons p where p.Name = 'Louis Vingo') and
      motherID in (select p.ID from Persons p where p.Name = 'Dianne Vingo')
```

It is rather tricky to combine this into a single subquery -- and not worth the effort.

Comment: This worked thank you, I wasn't splitting it up correctly